VQE applications which use the Pauli strings containing {I, X, Y, Z}
VQE is a quantum-classical hybrid algorithm which goal is to find the ground state of a Hamiltonian. The most well-known application of VQE is for chemistry simulation. A chemistry simulation can be written as   Hamiltonian and it can encode into many Pauli operators (mostly using Jordan–Wigner encoding).

QAOA is similar as VQE which also want to get the expectation value of Pauli operators in the end of the ansatz circuit. But in my understanding, QAOA only use the Pauli strings containing {I, Z}. I wonder whether there exist some QAOA applications which use the Pauli strings containing {I, X, Y, Z}. Also, are there some other applications which use the Pauli strings containing {I, X, Y, Z}? Thanks for answering!
